Flutter how to display existing images and newly picked images in one GridView.builder?
I am creating a screen for updating place details, where admin can view and delete existing images for that place or upload new images
[*update] Place Model:
import 'attraction.dart';
import 'restaurant.dart';
import 'review.dart';
import 'shopping.dart';

class Place {
  String id; // Unique identifier for the place
  String name;
  String description;
  String category;
  double? averageRating;
  List<Review>? reviews;
  Map<String, dynamic> operatingHours;
  Map<String, dynamic> address;
  List<String> contactInfo;
  List<String>? imageUrl; // URL to an image of the place

  Place({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.category,
    this.averageRating,
    this.reviews,
    required this.operatingHours,
    required this.address,
    required this.contactInfo,
    this.imageUrl,
  });

  // Factory method to create a Place from a map (e.g., JSON)
  factory Place.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    switch (json['category']) {
      case 'ATTRACTION':
        return Attraction.fromJson(json);
      case 'RESTAURANT':
        return Restaurant.fromJson(json);
      case 'SHOPPING':
        return Shopping.fromJson(json);
      default:
        return Place(
          id: json['id'],
          name: json['name'],
          description: json['description'],
          category: json['category'],
          averageRating: json['averageRatings'],
          reviews: json['reviews'] != null
              ? List<Review>.from(
                  json['reviews'].map((x) => Review.fromJson(x)))
              : null,
          operatingHours: json['operatingHours'],
          address: json['address'],
          contactInfo: List<String>.from(json['contact']),
          imageUrl: json["photos"] != null
              ? List<String>.from(
                  json['photos'].map((photo) => photo['path'] as String))
              : null,
        );
    }
  }

  // Method to convert Place to a map (e.g., for JSON)
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'category': category,
      'averageRatings': averageRating,
      'reviews': reviews?.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),
      'operatingHours': operatingHours,
      'address': address,
      'contact': contactInfo,
      'photos': imageUrl?.map((path) => {'path': path}).toList(),
    };
  }

  String get formattedContactInfo {
    if (contactInfo.isNotEmpty) {
      return contactInfo.first;
    }
    return 'No contact info available';
  }

  String get location {
    return "${address['street']}\n${address['city']}, ${address['state']} ${address['zipCode']}\n${address['country']}";
  }

  String get formattedOperatingHours {
    return operatingHours.entries.map((entry) {
      String day = entry.key;
      String startTime = entry.value['openingTime'] ?? 'N/A';
      String endTime = entry.value['closingTime'] ?? 'N/A';
      return "$day: $startTime - $endTime";
    }).join('\n');
  }

  int get totalReviews => reviews?.length ?? 0;
}


This is my GridView.builder: [dart file]
GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _newImages.length + provider.getImagesForPlace(widget.place.id).length,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index < _newImages.length) {
                    // Render new images
                    return Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Image.file(
                          _newImages[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          right: 5,
                          top: 5,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _newImages.removeAt(index);
                              });
                            },
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.cancel,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    // Render existing images
                    final existingImages = provider.getImagesForPlace(widget.place.id);
                    final existingImageIndex = index - _newImages.length;
                    return existingImages.isEmpty
                        ? Container() // Empty container if no existing images
                        : Image.memory(existingImages[existingImageIndex].bytes);
                  }
                },
              ),

Now, in above code:
1. _newImages is defined as:
final List<File> _newImages = [];

2. a. getImagesForPlace function is from where downloaded images can be retrieved. provider is used for state management, this how the function is :
List<MemoryImage> getImagesForPlace(String placeId) {
  return _placeImages[placeId] ?? [];
}

b. _placeImages is defined as:
final Map<String, List<MemoryImage>> _placeImages = {};

where downloaded images are stored
Now, I am getting error in GridView at itemCount
Error: The argument type 'num' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int?'.
                itemCount: _newImages.length + provider.getImagesForPlace(widget.place.id).length


Can you share more about widget.place
